# What kind of phrase is "did accept"?

Tags: punctuation, relative-clauses, phrase-choice

[Source](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/relativeclause.htm)

> Which Francine **did not accept**

Which kind of phrase is this bold part?

> To calm his angry girlfriend, Joey offered an apology **which Francine did not accept.**

Why no comma in bold part, though it seems unessential?

Comment: *To save time I wrote this example which illustrates my point*. It's really a stylistic choice whether to set off either of the clauses *to save time* or *which illustrates my point* with commas. In your specific example so far as I'm concerned it would be fine to start a new sentence after ***apology*** (or use a dash before the final clause/sentence if you prefer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Did not accept* is the negative or negated version of *accepted*. We use the word *did* there as part of the negative version. Another version is *accepted not*, but this is old-fashioned and is not standard in today's English.

Too many commas slow the reader down.

> To calm his angry girlfriend, Joey offered an apology which Francine did not accept

already has one comma. Even this comma is optional.

But to add a second comma so that you get

> To calm his angry girlfriend, Joey offered an apology,  which Francine did not accept

means that you have a four word independent clause

> Joey offered an apology

in between  two dependent clauses set off by commas.  If you actually pause where both commas are in this sentence it sounds ridiculous. (Notice my last sentence contains no commas, although some people might be tempted to use one or even two.)

If you really wanted the relative clause *which Francine did not accept* to be a non-restrictive relative clause, it might be better not to use the comma after *girlfriend*:

> To calm his angry girlfriend Joey offered an apology, which Francine did not accept.

Some people think you must have a comma after the introductory clause, but that is not correct. Punctuation varies.

I just read this sentence last night, which contains no commas; some people might want to insert one after *Swindon*:

> As they approached Swindon Strike’s phone rang.

(*The Silkworm*, by "Robert Galbraith", aka J. K.  Rowling.)

Swindon is a place name. But many American readers especially (who are not  familiar with this English place name) might be bothered by the lack of a comma after *Swindon*.

Comment: Why the first comma was optional? Will it be grammatical then?

Comment: Yes, the first comma is optional. Look at the last sentence I highlighted: *As they  approached Swindon Strike's phone rang.* There is no comma here after the introductory phrase *after they approached Swindon.* The comma is optional in this sentence,   and the  comma  after *to calm his angry girlfriend* is optional. Commas after most introductory phrases are optional.

Comment: Regarding Strike's phone, I think that English people might feel the need for a comma after Swindon, whereas Americans might think there should be one before Swindon.

Comment: Yes, indeed, @JavaLatte thanks for the proofread! It's been corrected.

Comment: Yet the author uses no comma, @Java.... either before or after Swindon. Unless my Kindle version is wrong.

Comment: Or maybe the author is...

Comment: I  don't see the need for a comma in the seven word sentence *As they approached Swindon Strike's phone rang.* If you disagree, you can contact the author, publisher or write your own answer. ;)